# How does stackOverflow submit their pages to the search engine in a very little time?

Tags: php, seo, stack-overflow

I have asked a question on stackoverflow and searched it on google in very little time it became on the 1st page and 1st link, I was wondered that how it can submit urls very quickly and get indexed?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about SEO.

Comment: Because the Google spiders crawl the site too quickly. You can achieve a somewhat-similar effect by increasing the crawl rate, but I'd say it depends on a variety of other factors, too.

Comment: @ShankarDamodaran I have also added SEO tag but I thought that there might be some work of php

Comment: Google has an algorithm for webpages.. It's a mix between eigen vectors/values and coding.

Comment: Please read  about SEO(Search Engine Optimization).

Comment: In any case, this question is off-topic for Stack Overflow. Please see  [what is on-topic for the site](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). [webmasters.se] might be more appropriate for this question.

Comment: @SonyaKrishna I have read about SEO but I didn't think that it could be very fast

Comment: Quite simply, it is an authority that is constantly updated and filled with activity. Google knows this and therefore chooses to index it frequently. Which can be really annoying when you see your question in google and you believe you have finally found the answer to your question.

Comment: http://www.rose-hulman.edu/~bryan/googleFinalVersionFixed.pdf will tell you about Googles search algorithm and the math behind it.

Comment: @user3133148, I did vote up for this question. But actually i think the question does not fit on SO rules.

Comment: @user3133148 You have to follow some SEO tricks in your website too to make the google spiders easy to crawl your site.Such tricks includes using meta tags in your pages ,seo friendly urls,creating site map for your website etc.Also you can advertise your website link in other popular sites.

Comment: @SonyaKrishna I feel like that is definitely a major portion behind it but then there is the mathematical aspect put on by Google's part, which is only in effect when the user puts in relevant information into the search engine itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because SO is one of the most popular websites, with thousands of links pointing in, a lot of trust and frequently updated content which keeps the google bot busy.

Indexing and crawl frequency depends mostly on how often you publish new content and how your site is backlinked. But even with a regular wp blog you can get your articles indexed and ranked in minutes.